# how to get the timestamp taken to insert the data into a table

Tags: java, sql, time, get

I am  storing  images in a table  i would like to get the time stamp taken to  insert the image into the table are their any  inbound  sql syntax for getting the  timestamp of inserted data ? or any  java syntax for getting the  timestamp of inserted data from the database  kindly help  out

Comment: Get the timestamp? So upon insertion you would like to know at what time the data was inserted? Or do you just want to store a current_timestamp along with the data?

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a function that is available in most database servers. So a sql like this should work.

`INSERT INTO <some_table> (<timestamp_column_name> VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

If you want to do it in java then you can do the following:-

```
 java.util.Date currentTime = new java.util.Date();
 System.out.println(new java.sql.Timestamp(currentTime.getTime())); //gets you the current  sql timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

It is going to vary by database.  This is going to work in both least Oracle and mysql:

```
insert into PRODUCE (color, weight, added_at) values ('red', '8 ounces', sysdate());
```

If you are using MySql, you can also add DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP to your column definition:

```
create table PRODUCE (
color varchar(20),
weight varchar(20),
added_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP
);

insert into PRODUCE (color, weight) values ('red', '8 ounces');
```

In Oracle, a separate trigger would need to be created to achieve the default value.